# Is there any way to add default value to react-dropzone (useDropzone)?

Tags: javascript, react-dropzone

I would like to initialize the react-dropzone (useDropzone) with an image. The users should be able to override (replace) it with their own images if they want to.

My desire would be to be able to add the default image by URL.
(ex. https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg)

Comment: and what did you do so far? please share the related codes.

Comment: I just pasted my ImageDropzone component here:

https://codepen.io/lsim1447/pen/MWvaKOz

Comment: please add it to the question with "edit" button. thanks

Comment: I would like to add a default image (by URL): 
https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg

Comment: please also add the codepen link to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the default image (a placeholder) as you defined the `error` section. you need to add an `img` element and pass the default image's URL to it .

with a prop checking, you can determine to show the placeholder image or use the user's uploaded image or even nothing.

I assume you store the `DropZone` result in a sample variable like `result`, so:

```
{
  !result && <img src={https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg}>
}
```

so the placeholder image will show if there is not a result